# Can you make 1 1 1 1 = 5?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Can you find a way to make 1 1 1 1 = 5 by adding any operations or symbols? You can use symbols such as these: +, -, *, !, ^, (). It is not limited to this list.

Good Luck!

P.S. You can not add any other numbers to the equation.

Comment: Why have these “find a way to make *blah* from *blah*” questions become so popular all of a sudden?

Comment: 1111 != 5 , you mad :) ?

Comment: Just consider $(1111)_n=5$ 

where

$$n=\frac{1}{3} \left(-2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{115+3 \sqrt{1473}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(115+3 \sqrt{1473}\right)}-1\right)$$

Comment: Kinda similar: 1(1-1)1 = 101 = 5 (in base 2).

Comment: Or 1(1-1) in base 5.

Comment: Or even (~1)-1 given three-bit ints.

Comment: @NL628 I guess that is just what people seem to like.

Comment: (1+1)(1+1)+1 = 5

Comment: @phuzi too many 1s, you could have just said 1 +1 + 1+ 1+ 1 = 5 if you had that many to use ;-)

Comment: Man, I joined this exchange to answer this, but association rep doesn't count to answer this :(.  From the perspective of someone who works with computers, I came up with these: `11/(1+1) = 5` as an int will implicitly drop remainders (seems a few people had variants of this answer).  The other one is `((11b) << 1) - 1 = 5` as 11b is equal to 3, shift left by one bit gives us 110b, or 6, and then subtract 1 to get 5.

Comment: @userNaN do you believe $0^0=1$? I fou know what I mean :P

Answer (score 93, accepted):

How about

> $(1+1+1)!-1$
>  = $6 -1$ = $5$

Comment: I'd say this is the better answer than mine, as mine concatenates two digits.

Comment: @Phylyp, that doesn't necessarily make your answer worse; the OP said nothing about concatenation, so we can just assume that we can leave a space blank if we want to :). Your answer is perfectly valid, I think.

Comment: @R.M That is true. I never said anything about concatenation. The answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: The interesting question is if you can do any better with the given symbols, or at least alternatively - and if not, how can you prove this?

Comment: @StrangePhoton, I saw your edit attempt – but my answer uses only 4 ones: (1+1+1)!-1. You might be confused about the 1 that appeared when I was solving the question (the expression is equivalent to 6-1). Only the numbers in the first expression are my answer. (And welcome to Puzzling SE! :)

Answer (score 53):

How about such a variant?

> ++(1+1+1+1)=5

Comment: Ladies and gents, we have a programmer amongst us! :-)

Comment: This doesn’t typically work in programming languages, though. And if it were valid in this type of challenge, you could just add the appropriate number of `++` to get anything…

Comment: Also most situations in which ++ means 'increment by 1', = will mean 'assign the item on the left to be equal to the item on the right' and == means 'is equal to'

Comment: This won't work in most (all of I know) programming languages as increment operator requires a l-value whereas 4 is an r-value.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu What? This works almost every programming languages

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson At least it doesn't in C/C++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde41bc9a5b1d16a

Comment: [Works just fine in Pip!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fW1vDUBsMNW1N//8HAA) (The output of `1` signifies "true.")

Comment: Doesn't work in C# either (`The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer`).

Comment: It also doesn't work in c#, python, js, or java. With the addition of C/C++ this covers quite a few important languages.

Answer (score 42):

Here's another solution:

> $1$E$1$ $/ (1 + 1)$ =  $5$

Where:

> E is the exponential notation symbol.
>
>  i.e. 1E1 = $1 \times 10^1$

Answer (score 36):

> 1 << 1 << $1 + 1 = 5$
>  
>  where << is a [bitwise-shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift)
>  
>  
>  1 << 1 = (binary) $10 = 2$
>  
>  2 << 1 = (binary) $100 = 4$, then finally add 1 to get 5

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Note, however, that the question asks for making the result of the operation to be 5, not 6. If you were aware of this and wanted to post it anyway for some reason, please address that in your answer.

Comment: @Lolgast. Nope. I just really derped on that one

Comment: @Lolgast. Found a way to fix it :)

Comment: Ah, we all derp sometimes :) Hopefully the downvoter will be kind enough to remove his downvote since this is now a valid answer (assuming he downvoted for not being valid). Eitherway I've upvoted

Comment: you may need  parens in some programming languages such as Python: [`(1<<1<<1)+1`](https://goo.gl/qvCTZS)

Comment: @jfs Agree! Otherwise we may get `(1 << 1) << (1 + 1)` or `1 << (1 << (1 + 1))`, for example, depending on the language. That is `8` or `16`, respectively.

Answer (score 35):

A little contrived:

> $⌊ 11 ÷ (1 + 1) ⌋ $

Explanation:

> $⌊ 11 ÷ (1 + 1) ⌋$ = $⌊ 11 ÷ 2 ⌋$ = $⌊ 5.5 ⌋ = 5$ 
>  
>  
>  Where ⌊  ⌋ is the [round down operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) (a.k.a. floor operator).

Comment: in Python: [`11 // (1+1)`](https://goo.gl/uiYivP)

Comment: @jfs That would be Python 3. In Python 2 you can get away with `11 / (1+1)` That being said, these comments spoil a bit, though.

Comment: Not contrived: you could just concatenate the first two `1`s if lexical operations are permitted. OP just suggests symbols and does specify if operations must be logical vs lexical.

Comment: @Arthur `//` has been in Python since 2.2. It just wasn't *necessary* until `/` was redefined to always mean floating-point division in 3.0 (or via the `__future__` mechanism.

Answer (score 27):

Here's another way:

> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{.\bar1}}+1+1=5$
>
>  Inside the square root is $.\bar1$, which is a recurring decimal equal to $1/9$.
>  The square root of $1/9$ is $1/3$, so the first fraction equals $3$.

Or, using just three 1s:

> $\frac{1}{.1+.1}=5$
>
>  Lots of ways to add a fourth $1$ to that, of course.

Comment: Upvoted for the second suggestion. Very nice.

Answer (score 26):

Slightly stretching the definition of 'adding a symbol' here:

> $1+1+1+1 <= 5$

Or, adding only a single symbol :

> $1111 >= 5$

Comment: How about $1111 \ne 5$?

Answer (score 8):

Using the [Euler totient $\varphi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function):

> $\varphi(11)/(1+1) = 5$

Using $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}$ (which contains no numbers :) there are all sorts of solutions, e.g.

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (1+1+1+1)/x = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 5/x$

Using the symbol "/" gives a subtle solution:

> $1111 \neq 5$

Edit: Using $\ln$:

> $\lceil \ln(11)\times (1+1)\rceil = 5$

Comment: Using a different $\phi$, the golden ratio, $\left((1+1)\phi-1\right)^{1+1}$ is five -- but that's five 1s.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question allows `to add symbols`, we could do:

> $1111 := 5$
>
>  Which defines 1111 to be 5. That can be seen as overloading a number to be a variable. In the same way as you use other symbols ($x,a,α,…$) as names for variables.

Another solution is:

> $\bar{1} = \bar{5}$
>  which uses the fact that these residue classes are equal in $ℤ/2ℤ$. I couldn't find a good English wikipedia page for explanation. On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring#Examples) wiki page the second example explains what $ℤ/2ℤ$ is. If you can speak German [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restklassenring) wikipedia article is pretty good.
>  Edit: Maybe you are more familiar with the notation $[1]=[5]$, I just favor the bar as you rarely can confuse it with other bar-notation such as complex numbers.

A third solution idea, which is not working so far, is:

> We know that $\sum_{i=0}^{∞}\frac{1}{2^n}= 2$, so  $\sum_{i=-1}^∞\frac{1}{(1+1)^n}=3$. The problem is - I already used all of my four $1$s for this...

Comment: Yeah, in my notation $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots , n\}$. Some people might use $[n]$ to mean "to round off to the closest integer to $n$" but I use $\lfloor n\rceil$ for that :P

Answer (score 2):

> $ 1+1+1-1 = ⌊\sqrt{5}⌋$

Of course, with enough nested square roots and rounding you can turn any positive number to 1.